# Knapsack with 2 constraits

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Given problem:

0/1-Knapsack problem, n items each having weight w_i and value v_i. Find the maximum total value of items whose weights sum up to weight W.

But there are two constraits:

1. The total **weight of all items** in the knapsack need to be **exactly W**.
2. The total **amount of items** must be **even**.

I want to find an algorithm that pays attention to both constraits. I already found out how I can pay attention to one of them at one time.

Here is my implementation which pays attention to constrait 1 (exact weight W):

```
public class KnapSackExactWeight {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] w = new int[] {4, 1, 5, 8, 3, 9, 2};  //weights
        int[] v = new int[] {2, 12, 8, 9, 3, 4, 3}; //values

        int n = w.length;
        int W = 10; // W (max weight)

        int[][] DP = new int[n+1][W+1];

        for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < W+1; j++) {
                if(i == 0 || j == 0) {
                    DP[i][j] = 0;
                } else if (j - w[i-1] >= 0) {
                    DP[i][j] = Math.max(DP[i-1][j], DP[i-1][j - w[i-1]] + v[i-1]);
                } else {
                    DP[i][j] = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Result: " + DP[n][W]);
    }
}

Result: 22
```

And here is my implementation which takes constrait 2 into account (even amount of items):

```
public class KnapSackEvenAmount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] weights = new int[] {4, 1, 5, 8, 3, 9, 2};    //weights
        int[] values = new int[] {2, 12, 8, 9, 3, 4, 3};    //values

        int n = weights.length;
        int W = 10;

        int[][] DP_odd = new int[n+1][W+1];
        int[][] DP_even = new int[n+1][W+1];

        for(int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < W+1; j++) {
                DP_even[i][j] = -1;
                DP_odd[i][j] = -1;
                if(i == 0 || j == 0) {
                    DP_odd[i][j] = -1;
                    DP_even[i][j] = 0;
                } else if(j - weights[i-1] >= 0) {
                    if(DP_odd[i-1][j - weights[i-1]] >= 0) {
                        DP_even[i][j] = Math.max(DP_even[i-1][j], DP_odd[i-1][j - weights[i-1]] + values[i-1]);
                    }
                    if(DP_even[i-1][j - weights[i-1]] >= 0) {
                        DP_odd[i][j] = Math.max(DP_odd[i-1][j], DP_even[i-1][j - weights[i-1]] + values[i-1]);
                    }
                }
                if(i > 0) {
                    DP_odd[i][j] = Math.max(DP_odd[i][j], DP_odd[i-1][j]);
                    DP_even[i][j] = Math.max(DP_even[i][j], DP_even[i-1][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Result: " + DP_even[n][W]);
    }
}

Result: 21
```

The idea for that: I use two DP tables (DP_even and DP_odd) and save the best solution for a knapsack with odd amount of items in DP_odd and for one with an even amount of items in DP_even.

Now my Problem is how to implement that both constraits work together. Is there a way to solve this?

(If anything is unclear in my question, just ask!)

Comment: What is wrong with the second algorithm?  Can you give an example where it doesn't give the right answer?  To me, it looks like it incorporates both constraints already?

Comment: Right now it uses w[1] (=1) and w[3] (=8), so the first constrait is not true as 1+8=9 != 10. The result should be 20 if both constrait are taken into account (w[0], w[1], w[4] and w[6] which would weigh 10 and have value 20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best way to do this problem but what I've done here is to initially reduce the problem to fit the constraints. First find the possible even number of items that weigh equal to the knapsack weight and then find the combination with highest value

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.Math.pow;

public class subSet{

void subset(int num,int n, int x[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        x[i]=0;
    for(i=n;num!=0;i--)
    {
        x[i]=num%2;
        num=num/2;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n,d,sum,present=0;
    int j;
    System.out.println("enter the number of items");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    n=sc.nextInt();
    int a[]=new int[n+1];
    int x[]=new int[n+1];
    System.out.println("enter the weights of items");
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        a[i]=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter the values of items");
    int v[]=new int[n+1];
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        v[i]=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter the max weight");
    d=sc.nextInt();

    int sol=0;int max=0;
    if(d>0)
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=Math.pow(2,n)-1;i++)
        {
            subSet s=new subSet();
            s.subset(i,n,x);
            sum=0;int count=0;
            for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
                if(x[j]==1)
                {
                    sum=sum+a[j];
                    count++;
                }
            sol=0;
            if(d==sum && count%2==0)
            {
                present=1;
                for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
                {
                    if(x[j]==1)
                        sol=v[j]+sol;
                    if(sol>max)
                        max=sol;
                }
            }

        }

    }
    if(present==0)
        System.out.println("Solution does not exists");
    else
        System.out.print("solution = "+max);

}
}
```

Comment: well it works, but as you already said it's not that efficient. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be this line:

```
DP_odd[i][j] = -1;
```

You give a penalty of only 1 for using an odd amount of times.

If you simply increase this to a larger negative number (e.g. max negative value for integers) I think your current algorithm should work.